# Объект и его значение

Tags: java, объекты

Я создал 4 объекта, каждый имеет свое значение `dichte` (плотность), и должен иметь свое значение `masse` (масса). Масса рассчитывается как **плотность * объем**. Как мне это реализовать? Что бы программа рассчитывала это значение и вставляла в объект?

```
public Baukloetze Eichen = new Baukloetze(1.2, 800d, masse);
public Baukloetze Fichten = new Baukloetze(1.2, 500d, masse);
public Baukloetze Granit = new Baukloetze(1.2, 2800d, masse);
public Baukloetze Stahl = new Baukloetze(1.2, 7900d, masse);

public double volume, dichte, masse;

public Baukloetze(double volume, double dichte, double masse) {
    this.dichte = dichte;
    this.volume = 1.2;
    this.masse = masse;
```

Comment: Ну так просто перемножьте нужные поля и результат задайте как значение ещё одного поля...

Comment: Как это сделать? может  быть Вы показали сам код?

Comment: this.masse = dichte * volume;    и убрать массу из конструктора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Baukloetze(double volume, double dichte) {
    this.dichte = dichte;
    this.volume = volume;
    masse = volume * dichte;
}
```

Comment: И для каждого объекта, будет расчитано и подставленно свое значение?

Comment: @SchweigertVitalij, да. Код выше это конструктор класса `Baukloetze`. Создавая класс `new Baukloetze(1.2, 800d);`, Вы передаете в конструктор необходимые параметры и они сохраняются в соответствующие переменные и рассчитывается из них масса, и так для каждого объекта.

Comment: Если у Вас есть немного времени, то не могли бы Вы мне еще помоч?

Comment: задача: Есть 4 вида кубиков с разной плотностью, но с одинаковой плотностью. Из кубиков можно составить столбик и расчитать силу с которой они действуют на поверхность. Можно добавлять кубики и убирать, соответсвенно только сверху этого столба. (плотность * объем = масса. Масса на 9,81 = сила).  Как мне лучше реализовать это все через LinkedList ? По заданию именно этот метод мне нужно использовать!

Comment: @SchweigertVitalij, если Вас устраивает вышеприведенный ответ на вопрос, отметьте его галочкой слева. Правила ресурса таковы, что 1 вопрос = 1 ответ. Если у Вас есть другие вопросы, пожалуйста, создайте новый.